# with tuple datastructure, how to sort two vectors keeping the pairs matched up?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdtuple

For a object, there are 2 attributes. For example, the object is a family. Then there are two vectors： member's height and member's weight.
what I want to do is to sort these members according to height. So I did something like the following code and there is an error:

```
     typedef std::tuple<double, char> lep_triplet;
     std::vector<lep_triplet> temporary_vec;
     std::sort( std::begin(temporary_vec), std::end(temporary_vec), [](const lep_triplet & left, const lep_triplet & right) { return  std::get<0>(left) > std::get<0>(right); });//
```

the error is:

```
/cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/Gcc/gcc620_x86_64_slc6/6.2.0/x86_64-slc6/include/c++/6.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::tuple<double, char>::tuple(float&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Could you please take a look at it? I think I made something improper in the lambda function part. But I could not fix it... Thank you!

Comment: The error in unrelated to the code shown and the sorting. Somewhere in your code you are trying to construct a `les_triplet` from a `float`. Have a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, finally I found the error is that I did not fill temporary_vec correctly. This method works. Thank you!